# using selenium xpath to click on href link, doesnt work

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, href

im trying to get the xpath of this, to click on the href link

```
<a href="/film/ah-fei-jing-juen/" class="frame has-menu" data-original-title="Days of Being Wild (1990)">
```

my code so far is

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/section/ul/li[1]/div/div/a").click
```

and ive tried using find element by id as well. appreciate any help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this XPATH expression:

```
(//ul[contains(@class,'poster-list -p70 -grid film-list clear')]//following::span[@class='overlay'])[1]
```

Note: In the above expression, at the end `[1]` indicates first movie from top-left. If you want to locate second movie(element), just change that to `[2]` and so on.

Full working code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://letterboxd.com/a2vre/films/by/rated-date/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//ul[contains(@class,'poster-list -p70 -grid film-list clear')]//following::span[@class='overlay'])[1]"))).click()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: i get the no such element for both, but the webpage still loads up. idk if it helps but the link only appears if the cursor hovers over the image.

Comment: Can you share the URL if it is public?

Comment: yup! here's the url https://letterboxd.com/a2vre/films/by/rated-date/ im trying to click on the first film from the left, days of being wild (1990)

Comment: I updated the XPATH and code in the answer. Try the latest code. It won't lead to page 2. Let me know if it works fine.

Comment: i just tried the new code u added and it finally works! thank u so much! I spent so long on this

Answer (score 1):

To find an element using the href you can try this xpath:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/film/ah-fei-jing-juen/']").click
```

Comment: You might want to add a wait strategy before this call, otherwise, the element may not be there by the time you called it https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html